# Twilio Flex, using Okta for SSO- Not working at all

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I've gone through the Okta SSO configuration described here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-identity-provider-integration-for-okta. I've pasted in all the relevant links and have configured both Okta AND Twilio Flex exactly per the instructions. All the users from Okta are supposed to pull through to the Twilio Flex app, but none are. The only account showing is my Twilio user account which was set up when I clicked the setup link to jumpstart my Flex installation.

When I attempt to login I DO get Okta's SSO login and I AM able to login with my Okta credentials, but after the successful login I'm given the following message:

```
{"code": 70002, "message": "no RelayState provided and no default redirect URL", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/70002", "status": 400}
```

It's interesting to note that Flex is now in GA (General Availability), but the set up instructions still say to point the flex app urls to `preview.twilio.com/iam/...`.

I feel like I'm missing a very simple, but incredibly crucial step.

Can anyone help? I'm now over 24 hours from when I first requested help from Twilio with zero response.

Comment: FWIW I haven't been able to get Azure AAD SSO to work either. I have a support ticket open, sadly the free Developer Support tier takes days for replies. :/

Comment: Hope you were helped by now, I started writing this comment several days ago, but got pulled away and forgot. I've got flex setup and working with Okta currently. I'm running it locally as well as from https://flex.twilio.com/. I'm not getting errors, but I did want to mention it does not sync users. When a new Okta user logs in it will create a worker under the Twilio Workspace (default I believe is called Flex Task Assignment).

Comment: As for the error you're getting, you may be able to resolve this in Okta. I have my RelayState field set to a blank (edit app > 2nd page using classic UI) value which says it should send a blank value. Okta docs -> https://developer.okta.com/standards/SAML/#understanding-sp-initiated-login-flow  I have mine empty and in Twilio I do not have a defualt redirect URL set (Flex > Single Sign On) .  Hope that is somewhat helpful. If you're running flex locally and have a repo, I'd be curious to see what your appConfig.js looks like.

Comment: Hi all, developer evangelist from Twilio here. Have you managed to get this sorted or a response from support yet?

Answer (score 2):

First, find your runtime domain here: https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/overview

Next, on the SSO page here: https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/users/single-sign-on

Fill in DEFAULT REDIRECT URL field with https://flex.twilio.com/{myRuntimeDomain}

This should fix the error.